# Management Studio 2016 doesn't have database diagram in the object explorer

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using Microsoft management studio v18
I don't know why it doesn't have a Database Diagram section for each database,
any idea?[as you can see there isn't any Database Diagram there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO9Mh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database diagrams were deprecated from v18 Preview 4.

[List of deprecated features here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#previous-ssms-releases)

Comment: The question already answered, you should not answer it again, a flag would be the right action

Comment: tnx for your answer, but what should I use instead?

Comment: @Sami Yes, you're right

Comment: @Mohammad You can download the general availability release (17.9) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @tmwoods thank you so much